How to use DbContextFactory with multi-tenancy in Blazor Server?
I have a multi-tenant Blazor Server App. Multitenancy is handled by Finbuckle.Multitenant.
I set up my tenant info based on the following article.
Currently, in my Startup.cs I have the following:
services.AddDbContextFactory<AppContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("App"));
});

However, I need to change this so that the DbContextFactory is registered with the DI after the app starts and the tenant is known.
Is this possible? How can I do this?

For something like multi-tenancy where you want to ensure attributes of the current tenant are applied, you want to create and register a locator to resolve the current user, and then use the alternate constructor for the factory.
For example if I create a CurrentUserLocator:
public interface ICurrentUserLocator
{
    UserTenantDetails GetCurrentUserTenantDetails();
}

Where the implementation returns a details for the current user session including the connection string for that tenant's DB. Register that interface and implementation into the container. Now when registering the DbContextFactory:
services.AddDbContextFactory<AppContext>((sp, options) =>
{
    ICurrentUserLocator userLocator = sp.GetService<ICurrentUserLocator>();
    string connectionString = userLocator.GetCurrentUserTenantDetails().ConnectionString;
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionString));
});

This is bare bones and you should handle scenarios like when no current user session details might be found. The Action for the options builder is called whenever a DbContextFactory goes to create a DbContext so this variant of the method injects the container (ServiceProvider) as a service locator for the action. With that we can Locate our own UserLocatorService which gives us our user details and connection string to feed to the DbContext instance.
